Allure html report integrated with Cypress truncates request and response body data
I have Cypress 13.1.0 integrated with Allure (allure-cypress v.3.0.4).
Each test step in the generated html report is displayed truncated to 132 chars maximum (see attachment).
truncation example
Is there a way to display full response and request body in each step?
Tried to play with cy logs and put the request/response body as an attachment. No luck.
Send request function:


const sendApiRequest = ({
  method,
  url,
  headers = {},
  body = null,
  queryParams = {},
}) => {
  return cy
    .request({
      method: method,
      url: url,
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
      qs: queryParams,
      failOnStatusCode: false,
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
        cy.log(`Request failed with status: ${response.status}`);
        cy.log(`Response body: ${JSON.stringify(response.body)}`);
        throw new Error(
          `API request failed with status: ${response.status} and response body: ${JSON.stringify(response.body)}`,
        );
      }
      return cy.wrap(response);
    });
};



cypress.config.js


const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
const { allureCypress } = require('allure-cypress/reporter');
const allureWriter = require('@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  reporterOptions: {
    charts: true,
    reportPageTitle: 'Test API',
    embeddedScreenshots: false,
    saveAllAttempts: false,
  },
  e2e: {
    experimentalRunAllSpecs: true,
    specPattern: 'cypress/api-specs/**/*.spec.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      allureWriter(on, config);
      allureCypress(on, config, {
        resultsDir: 'allure-results',
      });
      require('@cypress/grep/src/plugin')(config);
      return config;
    },
  },
  trashAssetsBeforeRuns: true,
  headless: true,
  env: {
    grepFilterSpec: true,
    grepOmitFiltered: true,
    allureReuseAfterSpec: true,
  },
});




Please show the test code to give context to the question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Provided the additional details in the first message of the topic.

Solved with the option in cypress.config.js


    stepsFromCommands: {
          maxArgumentLength: 1500,
        },



